# Is it possible to use both GIN index and pgvector index for querying in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, execution-plan, index-tuning

I have a table like below in postgres:

```sql
create table posts (
    id bigserial,
    tags text[],
    content text,
    content_embedding vector(512)
);

create index on posts using GIN(tags);
-- from pgvector
create index ON posts USING hnsw(content_embedding vector_cosine_ops) WITH (m = 24, ef_construction = 100);
```

Each row is basically a post in a blog with `content` storing its text, tags is an array of tags (e.g. `'{"database","coding"}'`), `content_embedding` is where I store a vector representation of `content` generated with some AI model which I hope to use for semantic search.

I want to run queries like below to get posts whose `tags` contain `database` or `hobby` and order them by how "similar" they are to a given vector (`'[...]'` below for the sake of brevity):

```sql
select id, (content_embedding <=> '[...]') as cosine_similarity from posts where tags && '{"database","hobby"}' ORDER BY cosine_distance ASC
```

However, it looks like the query plan from `explain analyze` does not make use of the vector index as I hope

```
 Sort  (cost=8081.77..8089.15 rows=2952 width=16) (actual time=10.444..10.445 rows=20 loops=1)
   Sort Key: ((content_embedding <=> '[...]'::vector))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts (cost=1698.88..7911.62 rows=2952 width=16) (actual time=9.966..10.424 rows=20 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (tags && '{database,hobby}'::text[])
         Heap Blocks: exact=19
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on posts_tags_idx  (cost=0.00..1698.14 rows=2952 width=0) (actual time=9.842..9.842 rows=20 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (tags && '{database,hobby}'::text[])
 Planning Time: 0.536 ms
 Execution Time: 10.496 ms
```

When I remove the `where` clause, I do see an index scan being used for sorting

```
 Index Scan using posts_content_embedding_idx on posts  (cost=164.90..41510.78 rows=301590 width=16)
   Order By: (content_embedding <=> '[...]'::vector)
```

I have around 300000 rows in `posts`. Is that a factor? Is there a way for postgres to use both the gin and hnsw indices? If it can't then how many rows is the limit before my query takes too long (>100ms)?

I'm aware that there are solutions built towards this use case of searching like Elasticsearch or maybe vector databases but I already have a postgres database and I hope to be able to stretch it as far as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism for PostgreSQL to combine those types of index usages.  A multicolumn GiST index can do it internally, but I don't know if `hnsw` can support something like that, I rather doubt it.  (And when GiST does that, it seems not to be very efficient at it)

> If it can't then how many rows is the limit before my query takes too long (>100ms)?

Surely you are in a better position to answer that than we are.  You already have the data and the system, just pick the most common tags and see what happens.